# Slather Coverage.profdata not found - Xcode 14.3 - Xcode 15.0

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, xcode15, slather

Premise: it works with Xcode 14.2

I have a problem with fastlane and slather, it gives me an error that it cannot find the `"code coverage folder"`

Here are some details

Fastlane file

```
slather(
      build_directory: "./DerivedData",
      scheme: "MyApp",
      workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
      proj: "./MyApp.xcodeproj",
      output_directory: "./DerivedData/testResult", 
      cobertura_xml: true,
      verbose: true
)
```

Error:

```
Exit status of command 'slather coverage --cobertura-xml --build-directory ./DerivedData --output-directory ./DerivedData/test-output/slatherOutput --ignore Pods/\* --ignore fastlane/\* --ignore build/\* --ignore DerivedData/\* --verbose --scheme ProjectName --workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace ./ProjectName.xcodeproj' was 1 instead of 0.

Slathering...
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slather-2.7.4/lib/slather/project.rb:239:in `profdata_coverage_dir': No coverage directory found. (StandardError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slather-2.7.4/lib/slather/project.rb:517:in `find_binary_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slather-2.7.4/lib/slather/project.rb:336:in `configure'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slather-2.7.4/lib/slather/command/coverage_command.rb:59:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/clamp-1.3.2/lib/clamp/command.rb:66:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/clamp-1.3.2/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:18:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/clamp-1.3.2/lib/clamp/command.rb:66:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/clamp-1.3.2/lib/clamp/command.rb:140:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slather-2.7.4/bin/slather:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/slather:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/slather:25:in `<main>'
No coverage directory found.

    Are you sure your project is generating coverage? Make sure you enable code coverage in the Test section of your Xcode scheme.
    Did you specify your Xcode scheme? (--scheme or 'scheme' in .slather.yml)
    If you're using a workspace, did you specify it? (--workspace or 'workspace' in .slather.yml)
    If you use a different Xcode configuration, did you specify it? (--configuration or 'configuration' in .slather.yml)
```

**With Xcode 14.2**

```
Processing coverage file: /Users/runner/work/repo/repo/DerivedData/Build/ProfileData/
C9A-EA9C-4732-A6CD-ED50D/Coverage.profdata
```

**With Xcode 14.3.x or Xcode 15**

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slather-2.7.5/lib/slather/project.rb:239:in `
profdata_coverage_dir': No coverage directory found. (StandardError)
```

Any ideas in order to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem